# running a task every five minutes without overlapping?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Quoting https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps ,

> ```
> $schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping();
> ```
>
> In this example, the `emails:send` Artisan command will be run every
>   minute if it is not already running.

What if I wanted the task to run every five minutes instead? Could I do this?:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, haven't tested it yet though. Maybe run a simple test of some sorts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this. [`command`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.html#method_command) returns an instance of Event the underlying code for `Event` has a fluent interface which allows you to chain these together in this way.

You can see this for yourself if you look at the [`withoutOverlapping`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L613) method.

```
/**
 * Do not allow the event to overlap each other.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function withoutOverlapping()
{
    $this->withoutOverlapping = true;
    return $this->skip(function () {
        return file_exists($this->mutexPath());
    });
}
```